# Is This LL(1) grammar

Tags: parsing, grammar, ll-grammar

It's really important to me, so please help me.
Is this grammar LL(1)?

```
S -> LAB
L -> d | ε
A -> dA | Ba
B -> Bb | ε
```

can anyone help me with LL(1) parsing table?
Am I right about this?

```
first(S) = {a,b,d}
first(L) = {d}
first(A) = {b,d}
first(B) = {b}

follow(S) = {$}
follow(L) = {a,b,d}
follow(A) = {b,$}
follow(B) = {$}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the [JFLAP tool](http://www.jflap.org/) on your grammar. JFLAP does not think your grammar is LL(1), but can try and build a parse table for it.

You could experiment with the grammar in JFLAP to make it LL(1) conformant.

Comment: Although I've answered the question, its probably more suitable for [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)